# How to sign an OKEx API request?

Tags: python, api, authentication, python-requests, sign

I keep getting an invalid sign error when trying to authenticate to the OKEx API, but am unable to see why my sign is not going through. Another eye might help?

Here is some context from the OKEx API documentation:

*---Signing Messages---

1. The OK-ACCESS-SIGN header is generated as follows: create a prehash
   string of timestamp + method + requestPath + body (where +
   represents String concatenation) prepare the Secret sign the prehash
   string with the Secret using the HMAC SHA256 encode the signature in
   the Base64 format Example:
   `sign=CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(timestamp + 'GET' + '/users/self/verify', SecretKey))`
2. The timestamp value is the same as the OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP header with nanosecond precision.
3. The request method should be UPPER CASE, i.e. GET and POST.
4. The requestPath is the path of requesting an endpoint. Example:
   `/orders?before=2&limit=30`
5. The body refers to the String of the request body. It can be omitted if there is no request body
   (frequently the case for GET requests). Example:
   `{"product_id":"BTC-USD-0309","order_id":"377454671037440"}`
6. The SecretKey is generated when you create an APIKey. Example:
   `22582BD0CFF14C41EDBF1AB98506286D*`

```py
import hmac
import base64
import requests
import json

from Secrets import okex_key
from Secrets import okex_secret
from Secrets import okex_pass

#get time
def get_time():
    urltime= 'https://www.okex.com/api/general/v3/time'
    response=requests.get(urltime)
    time=response.json()
    time=time['iso']
    return time

# signature
def signature(timestamp, method, request_path, body,secret_key):
    if str(body) == '{}' or str(body) == 'None':
        body = ''
    message = str(timestamp) + str.upper(method) + request_path + str(body)
    mac = hmac.new(bytes(secret_key, encoding='utf8'), bytes(message, encoding='utf-8'), digestmod='sha256')
    d = mac.digest()
    return base64.b64encode(d)


# set request header
def get_header():
    body= {}
    request= 'GET'
    endpoint= '/api/spot/v3/accounts'
    header = dict()
    header['CONTENT-TYPE'] = 'application/json'
    header['OK-ACCESS-KEY'] = okex_key
    header['OK-ACCESS-SIGN'] = signature(get_time(), request, endpoint , body, okex_secret)
    header['OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP'] = str(get_time())
    header['OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE'] = okex_pass
    return header


url = 'http://www.okex.com/api/spot/v3/accounts'
header = get_header()
response= requests.get(url, headers=header)
response.json()
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are giving two different time values when calculating the values for `OK-ACCESS-SIGN` and `OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP`. Put `get_time()` into a single variable and use it in both places.

```py
current_time = get_time()

header['OK-ACCESS-SIGN'] = signature(current_time, request, endpoint , body, okex_secret)
header['OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP'] = str(current_time)
```

Also note that currently, in `get_time`, you ask OKEx's servers what time it is. But if your computer's local time is reasonably correct (which you can check at https://time.is, for example) you can avoid doing that HTTP request and just use the local time.

```py
import datetime

def get_time():
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    t = now.isoformat("T", "milliseconds")
    return t + "Z"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution for signing request to OKEx API.
Thanks to [zoe-fleischer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15163005/zoe-fleischer) and [rok-povsic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365837/rok-povsic).

```
import base64
import datetime as dt
import hmac
import requests

APIKEY = "xxxxx"
APISECRET = "xxxx"
PASS = "xxxx"
BASE_URL = 'https://aws.okex.com'

def send_signed_request(http_method, url_path, payload={}):
    '''
    See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66486374/how-to-sign-an-okex-api-request
    '''
    def get_time():
        return dt.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()[:-3]+'Z'
    
    def signature(timestamp, method, request_path, body, secret_key):
        if str(body) == '{}' or str(body) == 'None':
            body = ''
        message = str(timestamp) + str.upper(method) + request_path + str(body)
        mac = hmac.new(bytes(secret_key, encoding='utf8'), bytes(message, encoding='utf-8'), digestmod='sha256')
        d = mac.digest()
        return base64.b64encode(d)
    
    # set request header
    def get_header(request='GET', endpoint='', body:dict=dict()):
        cur_time = get_time()
        header = dict()
        header['CONTENT-TYPE'] = 'application/json'
        header['OK-ACCESS-KEY'] = APIKEY
        header['OK-ACCESS-SIGN'] = signature(cur_time, request, endpoint , body, APISECRET)
        header['OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP'] = str(cur_time)
        header['OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE'] = PASS
        return header

    url = BASE_URL + url_path
    header = get_header(http_method, url_path, payload)
    print(url)
    print(header)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
    response.json()
    return response.json()

send_signed_request("GET", "/api/v5/account/balance", payload={})
```

Comment: Since the edit queue is full - please add the missing imports for this to work

import hmac
import base64

Comment: @Han Hi there! I don't even know ) 
Fixed with imports to become complete solution

Comment: Thankyou for this answer, it works and I am able to interact with the v5 APIs referring to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm executing the REST API in Postman and It's working fine for me. Below are the steps. (You need to use timestamp from okex time api)

GET : `https://www.okex.com/api/v5/account/balance`

Header:

```
OK-ACCESS-KEY:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx (API_KEY)
OK-ACCESS-SIGN:{{sign}}
OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP:{{timestamp}}
OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE:YOUR_PASSPHRASE
Content-Type:application/json
```

Pre-request Script

```
pm.sendRequest('https://www.okex.com/api/general/v3/time', function (err, res) {
        console.log('Response_ISO: '+res.json().iso);
        pm.expect(err).to.not.be.ok;
        var timestamp = res.json().iso;
        var sign = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(timestamp + 'GET' + '/api/v5/account/balance', 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY'));
        console.log(sign);

        postman.setEnvironmentVariable('timestamp',timestamp)  
        postman.setGlobalVariable('timestamp',timestamp) 

        postman.setEnvironmentVariable('sign',sign)  
        postman.setGlobalVariable('sign',sign)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not in python but i leave here if anyone comes here from Flutter dev, This is how i use in dart (Flutter) if anyone is interested with a simple post method. I buy a coin with a take profit and stop loss

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class ApiOKX {

  static Map<String, String> headers(String method, api, String body) {

    String time = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").format(DateTime.now().toUtc());
    List<int> messageBytes = utf8.encode('$time$method$api$body');
    List<int> key = utf8.encode('secret');
    Hmac hash = Hmac(sha256, key);
    Digest digest = hash.convert(messageBytes);
    String token = base64.encode(digest.bytes);

    var headers = {

      // For OKX
      'OK-ACCESS-KEY': 'accessKey',
      'OK-ACCESS-SIGN': accessSign,
      'OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': time,
      'OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': 'your password',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'x-simulated-trading': '1'
    };

    return headers;
  }

  static Future<String?> post(BuildContext context, api, {body, params})  async {

    var uri = Uri.parse('$base$api');

    print(uri);
    print('POST');
    var b = jsonEncode(body);
    log('body: $b');

    var response = await http.post(
        uri,
        headers: headers('POST', api, b),
        body: b
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return response.body;
    } else {
      print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}. ${response.body}');
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Calling from anywhere you want

```
  _buy() async {

    var payload =  {
      "instId": '${_leftCoin.text.toUpperCase()}-${_sideCoin.text.toUpperCase()}',
      "tdMode": "cash",
      "side": "buy",
      "ordType": "market",
      "sz": "100",
      "tpTriggerPx": _tp.text,
      "tpOrdPx": _tp.text,
      "slTriggerPx": _sl.text,
      "slOrdPx": _sl.text
    };

    var res = await ApiOKX.post(context, ApiOKX.order, body: payload);

    if (res != null) {

      var parsed = json.decode(res);

      if (parsed['data'].length > 0) {

        if (parsed['code'] == '0') {
          Toaster.success(context, parsed['data'][0]['sMsg']);
        }
        else {
          Toaster.error(context, parsed['data'][0]['sMsg']);
        }

      }
    }
  }
```