# okex API invalid authority

Tags: python

So I enter in my API, Secret and Pass using this code:

```py
import base64
import datetime as dt
import hmac
import requests

APIKEY = "xxxxx"
APISECRET = "xxxx"
PASS = "xxxx"
BASE_URL = 'https://aws.okex.com'

def send_signed_request(http_method, url_path, payload={}):
    '''
    See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66486374/how-to-sign-an-okex-api-request
    '''
    def get_time():
        return dt.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()[:-3]+'Z'
    
    def signature(timestamp, method, request_path, body, secret_key):
        if str(body) == '{}' or str(body) == 'None':
            body = ''
        message = str(timestamp) + str.upper(method) + request_path + str(body)
        mac = hmac.new(bytes(secret_key, encoding='utf8'), bytes(message, encoding='utf-8'), digestmod='sha256')
        d = mac.digest()
        return base64.b64encode(d)
    
    # set request header
    def get_header(request='GET', endpoint='', body:dict=dict()):
        cur_time = get_time()
        header = dict()
        header['CONTENT-TYPE'] = 'application/json'
        header['OK-ACCESS-KEY'] = APIKEY
        header['OK-ACCESS-SIGN'] = signature(cur_time, request, endpoint , body, APISECRET)
        header['OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP'] = str(cur_time)
        header['OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE'] = PASS
        return header

    url = BASE_URL + url_path
    header = get_header(http_method, url_path, payload)
    print(url)
    print(header)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
    print(response.json())
    return response.json()

send_signed_request("GET", "/api/v5/account/balance", payload={})
```

I get this error message:

> {'msg': 'Invalid Authority', 'code': '50114'}

Having trouble finding a fix if someone can help. I've looked on here and elsewhere for this specific issue.

Was expecting to get the list of balances on my account.

Comment: According to the documentation, 50114 means invalid authorization.  So I would guess that the key, secret, and/or password are wrong.

Comment: Thank you this was correct for my case, now Im getting {'msg': 'APIKey does not match current environment.', 'code': '50101'}

Answer (score 0):

add `x-simulated-trading: 1` to headers